# Products page powered by AngularJs visualization problem

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS alot in my projects most likely at Admin Panel or non public sides. But I'll need to use AngularJs in products page for a public web site.

Here the problem comes in ;
The page is loading pretty fast but for a millisecond I'm seeing some AngularJS tags, code also the product's html template/structure. For an example let's say I am seeing the codes below in products page;

{{product.name}} ({{product.count}})

these codes are flashing for second and page starts working as expected. 
I have tried to use ng-if, ng-show, ng-hide to prevent this flashing effect at start but it worked.

I would realy glad if found a solution to this problem.

btw, I am using AngularJs 1.6.9 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive on the elements that have tags flickering issue, e.g:

```
<p ng-cloak>{{ someValue }}</p>
```

It's purpose is to prevent AngularJS uncompiled templates from being displayed, therefore it should address your issue.

Comment: Hey @antonku yes you are right but unfortunately it is not working because I have large loads in page but your answer is true.  I will manuelly make the div invisible and when data loads i will make it visible again. For now it's the best choice. Thanks for you help

Comment: Hi @devekom, I am sorry that the answer does not work for your issue. Besides manually hiding the div you can also check the possibility to manually add `ng-cloak` styles in your css as suggested in this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jun/02/angularjs-ngcloak-problems-on-large-pages#Add-the-ng--cloak-Styles-manually

Comment: Hi @antonku I was looking exactly the same page and implementing in this way thanks for your interest :)

Comment: @devekom My pleasure :)